# Creating local scheduled events notifications with Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I apologise in advance for my fairly broad question, but I am just looking for some general guidance on how to approach the issue below.

I am developing my first app for android/iOS with Xamarin Forms. I need to do reminders(notifications) for medical use. As this is scheduled in advance I would just use local notifications. 
I have been browsing through the Xamarin documentation but I find it very confusing and lacking proper examples. 
I think I have to use dependency services as there is no xamarin.forms implementations as far as I can tell. What is the best way to go about this and does good examples exist for local notifications?

Also for the moment my application stores all data online, will it be possible to store/schedule these notifications with something like an event id for reference? I would also like to be able to perform actions on the notifications(from the lock screen), but this can wait.

Comment: You might find this plugin useful: https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin

Comment: You can use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to use Android native api- [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)